# css selector merging

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to merge this selector:

```
ul#social_footer li a:link,
ul#social_footer li a:visited {}
```

I want the same selector for the ul with ID #footer_navigate to be selected for both anchor states.

Is this the only way to do it?

```
ul#social_footer li a:link,
ul#social_footer li a:visited,
ul#footer_navigate li a:link,
ul#footer_navigate li a:visited {}
```

Comment: Another way to do it would be to add a class to each element that you want to use that style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, on the assumption there's no other `a` elements in there that you *don't* want to affect, shorten that to:

```
ul li a:link,
ul li a:visited {
    /* css */
}
```

This approach does present the problem that you'd have to override the given styles for other links that matched by the same selector.

I'd suggest using classes instead, though, to identify those links that share styles:

```
ul.navigation li a.happyColors:link
ul.navigation li a.happyColors:visited {
    /* CSS */
}
```

Which does, obviously, require editing of the html to add those (or whatever) classes you choose to use instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding the class made the most sense thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a additional common class at all tag `ul` that  should have your two selector.

In this case you can use only this css:

```
ul.*commonClass* li a:link, ul.*commonClass* li a:visited {}

<ul id="social_footer" class="*commonClass*" >...</ul>
<ul id="footer_navigate" class="*commonClass*" >...</ul>
```

Comment: Yea this made the most sense.. Stupid of me not to realize I can just do this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As I described **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75624293/best-way-to-combine-css-selectors/75624382#75624382)** you can use the new CSS function `:is()`.

It's pure css with [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is)

```
ul:is(#footer_navigate,#social_footer) li  a:is(:visited,:link) { }
```

**[More Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75624293/best-way-to-combine-css-selectors/75624382#75624382)**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this :

```
    ul#social_footer li a:link, ul#social_navigate li a:link{

    }

    ul#footer_footer li a:visited, ul#footer_navigate li a:visited{

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you have found adding a class as an acceptable answer (and it is). You may also want to check out [lesscss](http://lesscss.org/) as a way to programmatically apply css stylings.