# Best way to combine CSS selectors

Tags: css

I want to merge these two CSS. What are the possible ways to do this

```
.home .site-content .content-area{width: 100%;}
.archive.category .site-content .content-area{width: 100%;}
```

These two line of CSS should me merged in a single line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:is()`.
It's pure css with [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is)

```
:is(.home, .archive.category) .site-content .content-area {width: 100%;}
```

Comment: good use of the  `:is()` selector. With 92% support also productively usable in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

The vanilla CSS Selector would be:

```css
.home .site-content .content-area,
.archive.category .site-content .content-area {
  width: 100%;
}
```

As soon as you use a CSS Preprocessor such as SASS or LESS you can nest. Alternatively, you have to wait a while until WHATWG releases the specifications for CSS nesting. In SASS or LESS you can use:

```scss
.home,
.archive.category {
  .site-content . content-area {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

If you want to display it in one line, you can ofc write it in one line for a minified version.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `:is()` is [`:where()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where):

```css
:where(.home, .archive.category) .site-content .content-area {}
```

The difference between this and `:is()` is that:

> `:is()` counts towards the specificity of the overall selector (it takes the specificity of its most specific argument), whereas `:where()` has a specificity value of 0.
> – [`:is()` | MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is#difference_between_is_and_where)

Try it:

```css
:is(.home) .site-content .content-area {
  background: #ccc;
}

:where(.home, .archive.category) .site-content .content-area {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <div class="site-content">
    <div class="content-area">
      <code>.home</code>: <code>#ccc</code>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="archive category">
  <div class="site-content">
    <div class="content-area">
      <code>.archive.category</code>: <code>#ddd</code>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```